# SQL Server 2008 Threaded Comment System - What's More Efficient?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains both my posts and my comments. We only go one comment deep, no comments on comments. Right now, we're doing an ajax request for the posts, then grabbing the comments in another query, using the parent posts ID's to grab the appropriate child comments.

What I'm wanting to do is consolidate this into the most efficient, single query system I can.

**This leaves me to either using CROSS APPLY, or UNION, if I'm not mistaken, but there are some caveats:**

- We want to select the top 10 posts, and the top 2 comments for each
- Posts need to be listed in descending order
- Comments need to be listed in ascending order

Here's an example of our current queries for posts and comments:

Posts:

```
 SELECT TOP 10 ForumPostID, ForumID, ContentText, Hidden, S.Firstname, S.Lastname,   
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),DATEADD(hh,CASE
       WHEN DD.StartDate IS NOT NULL THEN 5 ELSE 6 
       END,
 FP.PostDate),126)+'Z' AS PostDate, 
 PostDate AS UglyTime, TopPostID, 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Admin.dbo.ForumPosts WHERE TopPostID = FP.ForumPostID) AS     
 'CommentCount',
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Admin.dbo.ForumLikes WHERE ForumPostID = FP.ForumPostID) AS 'Likes',      
 CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Admin.dbo.ForumLikes WHERE ForumPostID = FP.ForumPostID AND    
      Authuser = FP.Authuser) WHEN 0 THEN 'Like' ELSE 'You liked this.' END AS 'LikeText' 
 FROM Admin.dbo.ForumPosts FP 
 INNER JOIN Student.dbo.Student S 
      ON S.StudentUID = FP.Authuser
 INNER JOIN Admin.dbo.DayLightSavingsDates DD 
      ON FP.PostDate BETWEEN DD.StartDate AND DD.EndDate
 WHERE FP.ForumPostID NOT IN ( SELECT Top 0 ForumPostID FROM Admin.dbo.ForumPosts FP2 ORDER BY 
 FP2.ForumPostID DESC) 
 AND FP.Hidden = 'N' AND FP.ContentText <> '' 
 AND FP.PostType = 'post' 
 ORDER  BY FP.PostDate DESC
```

Comments:

```
SELECT TOP 50 ForumPostID, ForumID, ContentText, Hidden, S.Firstname, S.Lastname, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),DATEADD(hh,CASE
      WHEN DD.StartDate IS NOT NULL THEN 5 ELSE 6 END,
FP.PostDate),126)+'Z' AS PostDate,
PostDate AS UglyTime, TopPostID,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Admin.dbo.ForumPosts WHERE TopPostID = FP.ForumPostID) AS     
      'CommentCount', 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Admin.dbo.ForumLikes WHERE ForumPostID = FP.ForumPostID) AS 'Likes',
CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Admin.dbo.ForumLikes WHERE ForumPostID = FP.ForumPostID AND 
     Authuser = FP.Authuser) WHEN 0 THEN 'Like' ELSE 'You liked this.' END AS 'LikeText' 
FROM Admin.dbo.ForumPosts FP 
INNER JOIN Student .dbo.Student S 
ON S.StudentUID = FP.Authuser 
INNER JOIN Admin.dbo.DayLightSavingsDates DD ON FP.PostDate BETWEEN DD.StartDate AND DD.EndDate 
WHERE FP.ForumPostID NOT IN 
    ( SELECT Top 0 ForumPostID FROM Admin.dbo.ForumPosts FP2 ORDER BY FP2.ForumPostID DESC) 
AND FP.ForumPostID IN 
   (SELECT Top 2 ForumPostID FROM Admin.dbo.ForumPosts  FP3 WHERE FP3.TopPostID = FP.TopPostID 
       ORDER BY FP3.PostDate DESC) 
AND FP.Hidden = 'N' 
AND FP.ContentText <> '' 
AND FP.PostType = 'comment' 
AND FP.TopPostID IN ( 373, 371, 370, 369, 368, 367, 366, 365, 364, 363 )
ORDER BY FP.ForumPostID ASC
```

Comment: -1: Format your code in a readable way!

Comment: Sorry, it submitted before I was ready for it to, although I didn't click the button. It should be a bit better now.

Comment: *The button clicked itself! I swear!*

Comment: How can you possibly MAINTAIN that? There is much more than a performance problem here, if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

The most important advice that can be given here is that **you need to look at the execution plan.** I don't know a way around that. The query is too complex to give specific advice.

One thing though: You have a lot of expressions like "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Admin.dbo.ForumPosts WHERE TopPostID = FP.ForumPostID)". The SQL Server query optimizer has problems around using such expressions in computations. It sometimes fails to convert them into a normal join, preventing a lot of optimizations. You might want to convert those into joins. The IN-clauses however are safe as far as I can tell right now.

Comment: I would keep those counts as a field in the table and maitnain them via triggers. Count is a very heavy operation. You totally kill the need when you maintain counts.